# Random A everywhere in HTML page

Tags: html

I just started learning HTML and I'm getting all these capital As everywhere in my page when I load it in I.E. or Firefox

For example

```
<p style="color:red; text-align:center; text-shadow: 2px 2px 
yellow;">
Hello I'm new to HTML but -j won't help -A idk why! & bye.
```

And it'll show up as

```
 HelloÂ I'm new toÂÂ HTML butÂ -j wontÂ help -ÂÂ idk whyÂ! & byeÂ.
```

Comment: Artifacts from copy/paste. Or not encoded as UTF-8. Is this happening when you just type out and save? Can you paste the whole html file?

Comment: You're not, by any chance, using Microsoft Word or any similar rich text editor for your HTML coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with HTML encoding. Your file is probably encoded in UTF-8, and your browser is probably trying to read it as if it were encoded in ISO-8859-1. Adding a charset declaration inside you head tags like this should fix your problem:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    // Your text here
  </body>
</html>
```